# auto-insert-alist

Tags: template

I'd like to insert

```
#+SETUPFILE: ~/.emacs.d/org-templates/level-0.org
```

to each `.org` file that I intend to publish.

I opened the variable `auto-insert-alist` but I cannot figure out where to paste my insert.

Can you help?

Can I add `auto-insert-alist` to my init file instead of customizing it in Quick Customization window?

Thanks.
**EDİT**
[image]

**EDIT:**

I found this code [here](http://www.howardism.org/Technical/Emacs/templates-tutorial.html)

```
   (use-package autoinsert
      :init
      ;; Don't want to be prompted before insertion:
      (setq auto-insert-query nil)

      (setq auto-insert-directory (locate-user-emacs-file "templates"))
      (add-hook 'find-file-hook 'auto-insert)
      (auto-insert-mode 1)

      :config
      (define-auto-insert "\\.html?$" "default-html.html"))
```

This would work for me. But I didn't understand this line

```
      (setq auto-insert-directory (locate-user-emacs-file "templates"))
```

Do I need to create a `templates` file?

Comment: Yes, but... any particular reason you prefer not to use Customize? It seems to me that going by your problem description, Customize is exactly what you need, since it takes care of the enclosing syntax for you.

Comment: ok. Where do I paste the `#+SETUPFILE: ~/.emacs.d/org-templates/level-0.org` in the function. It looks very complicated (my elisp is not that good)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bypass both `customize` and `use-package`[1]. Add something like this to your init file, changing the definition of `auto-insert-directory` to whatever you want and adding dotted pairs of `(mode . "mode.template")` for each mode that you are interested in; e.g.:

```el
(setq auto-insert-directory "/path/to/templates/")
(setq auto-insert-alist '(
                          ;; templates for python and html mode
                          ;; are examples
                          (python-mode   . "python.template")
                          (html-mode     . "html.template")
                          (org-mode      . "org.template")

                          ;; more such pairs for other modes
                          ;; can be added here...
              ))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'auto-insert)
```

Then create the corresponding files in your `templates` directory. For Org mode, create `org.template` containing this:

```
#+SETUPFILE: ~/.emacs.d/org-templates/level-0.org
```

and whatever you want for the other modes. Restart emacs and open a new Org mode file.

---

[1] I would normally *not*   bypass `customize` but it seems that the interface is too complicated in this case. As for `use-package`, IMO a prerequisite to its usage would be to understand it very well at a high level (and in some detail at the lower levels, at least to the extent of what its constructs would translate to), and be able to debug problems with it. I have a vague understanding of it at a high level, but I do not meet most of these prerequisites, so I don't use it.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. I added also `(setq auto-insert-query nil)` to eliminate the query.

Comment: What are the existing rules in the Customize? Are they examples? Some of them look like C and C++ templates. But others may be used by emacs. Is this true? I first deleted them and then I thought they are needed and reverted. For anyone trying to do this in Customize, I believe you go to the end and click the "Insert" button there to create a new rule.

Answer (score 2):

It is unusually complicated for a customize interface, that's true. I'd go so far as to say the code that defines `auto-insert-alist` needs to be re-written to present a clearer interface making better use of Customize features.

Anyway... you need to enter `org-mode` into the first field (as "Major mode") and `(nil "#+SETUPFILE: ~/.emacs.d/...")`-- that is, a  Lisp list of two elements, with `nil` as the first element -- into the second field (as "Skeleton or vector").

It's that second field interface that really needs to be re-written IMO. We should be able to just enter the text we want, with no enclosing quotes, much less quotes *and* an enclosing list.

Comment: Thanks. I filled the form as per your answer but when I create a new `.org` file I don't see the snippet. I added the screenshot in my question. What am I doing wrong. And do I need to delete the other stuff under my entry?