# Help with yasnippets installation

Tags: yasnippet

Recently, [I asked](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/73312/auto-insert-alist) about inserting a snippet with `auto-insert-alist`. That works but now I thought about using Snippets for blockquote, for inserting images, etc. I’ve been trying to install Yasnippets without success so far. I watched most of the Youtube videos but they all seem to do it differently.

So far I downloaded yasnippets and yasnippets-snippets`

[image]

and added

```
(add-to-list 'load-path
              "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)
```

to my `.emacs` file.

But when I go to `emacs.d` folder I don’t see a `plugins` folder or a `yasnippet` file.

[image]

Do I need to create those?

Can you help me install Yasnippets? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, as it is, this works. I created a new snippet and tested it and it worked. So, I don't need to create this directory `"~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet"` ?

Comment: After you created the first snippet, to be saved it needed the directory to exist and created if for you. If you don't want to have files created everywhere by packages, use `no-littering` (https://github.com/emacscollective/no-littering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install `yasnippet` with `M-x package-install RET yasnippet RET`,
and the expression `(require 'yasnippet)` is enough, the package is already
installed in `elpa` folder; no need here for `~/.emacs.d/pluggins/yasnippet`
or `load-path`.

Also, you can install same way the package `yasnippet-snippets`, and require it
in usual way (it is a collection of snippets created by someone else).

The problem(s) may apear if you want to create your snippets - for what I can see
you already have a folder `snippets` created, there will go your new snippets,
but you should place them inside other folders, corresponding to the mode in use.
(e.g. in `snippets`create a folder `python-mode` and save there a new python snippet).
You need to load those new snippets, so after requiring `yasnippet-snippets` add the
expression `(yas-reload-all)` to have all ready for work.